# How to perform Variable Overloading in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I understand that you are in fact able to overload a function in C++. So i am in search of if i can use the same sort of principal with variables

**Example Code**

`Int i;`
`Char i;`
 `cin >> i;`

I have taken a quick peek around the forums and not many clear answers have been dished out. This sort of thing is supposedly doable in python.

Comment: But what would those three statements actually do?

Comment: Enable me to use the cin to dictate which variable is in use then dictate when i am done by changing the variable to void or null

Comment: Methinks you need to fluff up the example a little.

Comment: You can't. C has unions which get something similar done and you can shadow a variable in a different scope such as `int i; { char i; }`. But that's not the same.

Comment: You cannot overload variables.  In each scope all variables need a unique name to that scope.

Comment: That "Example code" looks a bit too minimal to me. I don't really understand what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks Nathan thats the Answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan said:

> You cannot overload variables. In each scope all variables need a unique name to that scope.